Does Blender support multiple sets of marked edges in Freestyle?
For Freestyle, is there only one such an edge set for storing the marked edges?
I think it would be very useful if there are many edge sets for Freestyle. For example, we may then use different styles for different edges of the same objects.
If Blender does not support this feature, what is the best workaround to achieve similar effects?
I mean, for example, how to select two different edge sets from the same objects, so that the first line set operates on the first edge set, while the second line set deals with the second edge set.
Background
We all know that we can mark some edges for freestyle like this:

By clicking "Mark Freestyle Edge" as shown above, we add those edges to a set that can be used for freestyle rendering.

And at the freestyle panel, we can only click the "Edge Mark" checkbox to use the marked edge set. It seems that there is only one such an edge set in Freestyle.
